# Spot idle dwellers

Tags: fallout-shelter

How can I know which dwellers are idle without scrolling through my list of dwellers? I'm talking about those who don't have an assigned job and are just walking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When looking at the list of dwellers, you can see idle dwellers by sorting with the "Status" header. The dwellers on Coffee Break (idle), or in the residence, will have a blank status and show up at the top of the list. This should be language agnostic.

Comment: I'm surprised I didn't know this. Good tip!

Answer (score 5):

Without using the list, you can spot them more easily by zooming out (to the point where you get 2D graphics and no working animations). They will likely be the only ones moving at all.

Otherwise, remember that the dweller list can be sorted by tapping the "Job" column header. This way, everyone is grouped by their jobs, and it's easy to find the "Coffee Break" people.

Comment: Zooming out might be a solution, even if my screen is not that big.
Sorting by jobs isn't that useful because I'm playing in french and it says "Pause café" wich is near the end of the list...

Comment: Mine aren't alphabetically sorted, but it may still be the case that they end up near the bottom. Still, it's reliable if you have a large vault.